# How can I remove empty double quotes from a CSV file in Python?

Tags: python

How do I remove empty double quotes from my CSV file using Python?

Here is what the file currently looks like:

```
"text","more text","","other text","","text"
```

Here is what I want it to look like:

```
"text","more text",,"other text",,"text"
```

Comment: You want to remove all quotes? Or just the ones around empty fields?

Comment: Is this in a dataframe structure that can be loaded into pandas or has to be read line by line?

Comment: Will be in a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Just the ones around empty fields.

Comment: For String: `re.sub('\"\"','',myStr)`, will write for pandas soon

Comment: If you know how to use `with open` or even just `read the file` into a string you can simply use `file_string.replace(',\"\",', ',,')`

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution is to use the `quotechar` option from [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.reader), then filter empty fields:

```py
import csv

with open('test.csv', newline='') as csvf:
    for row in csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=',', quotechar='"'):
        row = filter(lambda v: v, row)
        # Now row is just an iterator containing non-empty strings
        # You can use it as you please, for example: 
        print(', '.join(row))
```

If instead of removing empty fields you need to replace them by a given value (like `None`):

```py
import csv

def read(file, placeholder=None):
    with open(file, newline='') as csvf:
        for row in csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=',', quotechar='"'):
            yield [v if v else placeholder for v in row]

for row in read('test.csv'):
    pass # Do something with row
```

If for example you need to print it to stdout with surroundings double quotes (which is a silly example):

```py
for row in read('test.csv'):
    print(', '.join(f'"{v}"' if v else '' for v in row))
```

Comment: You can't just remove the empty fields that messes up the alignment of the columns. But still the answer is to parse the file and then write it out again with different quoting options.

Comment: Ok, I'll update my answer to replace the values with a placeholder :).

Comment: I really like this answer. Very elegant use of functional python.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
>>> s=""""text","more text","","other text","","text" """
>>> s
'"text","more text","","other text","","text" '
>>> s.replace('""','')
'"text","more text",,"other text",,"text" '
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of a lambda function and some pandas magic will increase speed greatly, once your DataFrame is loaded you will obtain something like

[image: Before Processing]

Then you just need to write a lambda function

```
replacer = lambda x: x.replace('""','')
df = df.apply(replacer)
```

Which does the operation you are looking for and gives you
[image: After Applying replacer]

Then just use `df.to_csv(filepathAsStr)` to save changes to disk or just continue with the operations you need, `df.apply()` parallelizes across the dataframe so this will improve performance significantly compared to simple `str.replace` or any method that uses serial computation.

Comment: Also checkout the link to see other ways you can apply the lambda function https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_apply_operations_to_dataframes/